# How to serialize an integer

Tags: python

How may I serialize an integer in the following program, I am unable to serialize it.

```py
import serial
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

#from Serialcomm import *

import Serialcomm


def GenerateXML(serialcomm):
    root=xml.Element("SerialParameter")
    
    child1=xml.Element("Portname")
    child1.text="COM5"
    root.append(child1)
    
    child2=xml.Element("Baudrate")
    child2.text="9600"
    root.append(child2)
    
    child3=xml.Element("serial.Parity")
    child3.text=serial.PARITY_NONE
    root.append(child3)
    
    child4=xml.Element("Stopbits")
    child4.text=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    root.append(child4)
    
    child5=xml.Element("Bytesize")
    child5.text=serial.EIGHTBITS
    root.append(child5)
    
    child6=xml.Element("Timeout")
    child6.text=1
    root.append(child6)
    
    
    
    tree=xml.ElementTree(root)
    with open(serialcomm,"wb") as files:
        tree.write(files)
    
    
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    GenerateXML("SerialSettings.xml")
```

Comment: Try this:- child6.text='1'

Comment: it is still a string how can i get value in integer

Comment: XML is entirely text based

Comment: @Abhijeetsingh please add more context around the question, what is the expected output, what output/error you are getting.